# Cannot use custom type inside an interface

Tags: typescript

I seem unable to understand why I cannot use custom type inside an interface.

I have the following definition:

```
type Operation = 'update'|'remove'|'add'
interface Rule {
  op: Operation
  path:string
  value?:any
}

function applyDiff<Output>(rules: Rule[], obj: object): Output;
```

but I receive `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Operation'` as an error at this failing test:

```
const obj = {a: {b:1, c:2}}
const rules = [
  {op: 'update', path: 'a.c', value:10},
] 
const result = applyDiff(rules, obj)
```

but this code works just fine:

```
function fn(x: number, y: 'add'|'remove'|'update'){
  return x > 1 && y === 'add'
  
}
const result = fn(1, 'remove')
```

What I am missing here? I would appreciate any helpful guidance on the matter. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the simple solution:

```
const rules: Rule[] = [
        // ^------^
  {op: 'update', path: 'a.c', value:10},
]
```

But why doesn't that work to begin with? Because the *inferred* type of `rules` is `{op: string; path: string; value: number}[]`, and there are lots of `string`s that aren't any of the values in the `Operation` union. Objects and arrays are *mutable*, so there's nothing to prevent the value of `op` changing (e.g. pushing a new object into the array, or mutating the existing object in the array) between defining `rules` and passing it to `applyDiff`.

This also suggests some other solutions:

1. Pass the array directly to the function:

   ```
   const result = applyDiff([
     {op: 'update', path: 'a.c', value:10},
   ], obj);
   ```

   Here there's no way for the values to change between defining the array and passing it to `applyDiff`, so the narrower type `{op: 'update'; path: 'a.c'; value: 10}[]` is inferred.
2. Use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to explicitly narrow the type of the rule:

   ```
   const rules = [
     {op: 'update', path: 'a.c', value:10} as const,
                                       // ^-------^
   ];
   ```

   This tells the compiler you consider that object to be immutable, which leads it to infer a narrower type for `rules` too. You could instead explicitly narrow the type of the `op`:

   ```
   const rules = [
     {op: 'update' as const, path: 'a.c', value:10},
               // ^-------^
   ];
   ```

   with similar effects.

Comment: That definitely works, but if that is the correct answer, then this works as expected and my question is kind of invalid. My issue is that this definition is part of library and I test what the user receives out-of-the-box, which in this case is not much. I might as well leave `op` type to be `string`. Thank you for the fast reply.

Comment: I just saw the suggestion with `const` - I was looking for something like that. Much appreciated.

Comment: @DejanToteff which definition is part of the library? It sounds like the question might not have fully represented the context.

Comment: the part with `appyDiff` declaration. But the suggestion with `const` works for me just fine. I haven't mentioned the context as I though that it is not relevant, but I will sure do include it on my next question.